# intent RECORD_SOUND_ACTION on LGP500

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, audiorecord

I am writing code to run RECORD_SOUND

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AUDIO_RESULT);
```

works on all phones, but it crashes LGP500

what is the problem?

```
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at com.webparadox.tonquer.Map.sound(Map.java:537)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at com.webparadox.tonquer.Map.onClick(Map.java:559)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
04-28 14:54:18.754: E/AndroidRuntime(10446):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does the stack trace and Logcat say when you start the activity?

Answer (score 0):

I myself have found working with the audio recordind in android to be the worst kind of work. As the implementation of the audio recorder is left to the OEM, not all phones work as they should with Intents, some don't return anything and some always return ACTIVITY_CANCELED.

It seems like lg has not even implemented anything to handle the voice recording in the p500 phones, or atleast not set up their voice recorded to catch the intent calls. You could try to Install an another sound recorded to the phone and see if it works.

BTW, I suppose you have set up your permissions right, right? :P